# Understanding the windows equivalent of braces

Tags: paths, rm

I am following a manual written for ubuntu, however I am in a windows environment.
I understand the rm -rfv, but I have no idea what the braces do in the line below, I want to run the equivalent in windows.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
rm –rfv /srv/payara/{tmp/*,payara5/glassfish/domains/domain1/{generated,osgi-cache}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `man bash` ... specifically:

```
   Brace Expansion
       Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be generated.  This mechanism is similar to  pathname  expansion,
       but  the  filenames generated need not exist.  Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional preamble, followed by
       either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence expression between a pair of braces, followed  by  an  optional  post‐
       script.   The  preamble  is  prefixed  to  each string contained within the braces, and the postscript is then appended to each
       resulting string, expanding left to right.

       Brace expansions may be nested.  The results of each expanded string are not sorted; left to right  order  is  preserved.   For
       example, a{d,c,b}e expands into `ade ace abe'.

       A  sequence  expression  takes  the  form  {x..y[..incr]}, where x and y are either integers or single characters, and incr, an
       optional increment, is an integer.  When integers are supplied, the expression expands to each number between x and  y,  inclu‐
       sive.   Supplied  integers  may be prefixed with 0 to force each term to have the same width.  When either x or y begins with a
       zero, the shell attempts to force all generated terms to contain the same number of digits, zero-padding where necessary.  When
       characters  are  supplied,  the  expression  expands  to each character lexicographically between x and y, inclusive, using the
       default C locale.  Note that both x and y must be of the same type.  When the increment is supplied, it is used as the  differ‐
       ence between each term.  The default increment is 1 or -1 as appropriate.

       Brace  expansion  is performed before any other expansions, and any characters special to other expansions are preserved in the
       result.  It is strictly textual.  Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation to the context of the expansion or the  text
       between the braces.

       A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or a valid
       sequence expression.  Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.  A { or , may be quoted  with  a  backslash  to
       prevent  its  being  considered  part of a brace expression.  To avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string ${ is not
       considered eligible for brace expansion.

       This construct is typically used as shorthand when the common prefix of the strings to be generated is longer than in the above
       example:

              mkdir /usr/local/src/bash/{old,new,dist,bugs}
       or
              chown root /usr/{ucb/{ex,edit},lib/{ex?.?*,how_ex}}

       Brace  expansion  introduces  a  slight  incompatibility  with historical versions of sh.  sh does not treat opening or closing
       braces specially when they appear as part of a word, and preserves them in the output.  Bash removes braces  from  words  as  a
       consequence  of  brace  expansion.  For example, a word entered to sh as file{1,2} appears identically in the output.  The same
       word is output as file1 file2 after expansion by bash.  If strict compatibility with sh is desired,  start  bash  with  the  +B
       option or disable brace expansion with the +B option to the set command (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).
```